# Trying to add items to a database using php

Tags: php, post

I am trying to a items to my database (sql) using php and a form, however the data is not being added and nothing seems to happening i just stay on the create.php page.

php code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "PolyTest";

// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname)

$doorName = $_POST['doorName'];
$doorDes = $_POST['doorDes'];
$doorPrice = $_POST('doorPrice');
$doorColour = $_POST('doorColour');
$doorImage = $_POST['doorImage'];

if(!$_POST['submit']){
   echo "please fill in the boxs";
   header('Location: dooradd.php');
} else {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO Doors ('ID', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'colour', 'image') VALUES(NULL, '$doorName', '$doorDes', '$doorPrice', '$doorColour', '$doorImage')") or die(mysql_error());
   echo "Door been added!";
   header('Location: doorlist.php');
 }
?>
```

HTML FORM

```
<form class="add" action="doorCreate.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="doorName" value="doorName">
  <input type="text" name="doorDes" value="doorDes">
  <input type="text" name="doorPrice" value="doorPrice">
  <input type="text" name="doorColour" value="doorColour">
  <input type="text" name="doorImage" value="doorImage">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It's kinda sad how many times we need to say this but **do not use the mysql_** functions... Deprecated for so long...  Use **mysqli**.

Comment: Try to add a value to the `submit` in your form. Does that help? As you check the value of submit which should be false if no value is submitted.

Comment: [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is deprecated.  Also, you should be doing some kind of validation of your POST variables before sending them off to your database in order to mitigate [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/), errors in your data and SQL errors.

Comment: Don't `echo` if you use `header`. It will make it do nothing.

Comment: Do something happens when you click on submit? Does the page change? Do you have any output?

Comment: `$doorPrice = $_POST('doorPrice');`
`$doorColour = $_POST('doorColour');`

These two should really be 

`$doorPrice = $_POST['doorPrice'];`
`$doorColour = $_POST['doorColour'];`

Comment: You may want to try turn on error reporting `error_reporting(-1);`
`ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: It should rise an error, there are many errors. How are you getting nothing?

Comment: I am getting nothing

Comment: @gurps Nothing is a blank page or no action when cliking on submit?

Comment: @KV Nothing is a blank page sorry

Comment: @gurps Do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Check the PHP error log on the server.

Answer (score 3):

change `mysql_select_db($dbname)` with `mysql_select_db($dbname);`

and change;

```
$doorPrice = $_POST('doorPrice');
$doorColour = $_POST('doorColour');
```

with

```
$doorPrice = $_POST['doorPrice'];
$doorColour = $_POST['doorColour'];
```